# How does angular prioritize routes - top level vs child

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Suppose I have defined a top level route with the path '/some/childr':

```
[{ path: '/some/childr'}]
```

Then I have another top level route `/some` with child route `/childr`:

```
[{ path: '/some', children: ['/childr']}]
```

so basically they both should react to `/some/childr`. Now I navigate to `/some/childr` in a browser, which route takes priority?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#wildcard-route) the router selects the route with a **first match wins strategy**.

So if you have defined routes as below then it will first match with `/some/childr` route and load `MyComponent`.

```
[
  { path: '/some/childr', component: MyComponent},
  {
    path: '/some',
    children: [
      {
        path: '/childr', component: ChildComponent
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And if you have defined routes as below then it will load `ChildComponent`.

```
[
  {
    path: '/some',
    children: [
      {
        path: '/childr', component: ChildComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: '/some/childr', component: MyComponent}
]
```